# Setting the SVM discriminant value in PyML

Tags: python, svm, pyml

I'm using PyML's SVM to classify reads, but would like to set the discriminant to a higher value than the default (which I assume is 0). How do I do it?

Ps. I'm using a linear kernel with the liblinear-optimizer if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roundabout way of doing it below:

Use the `result.getDecisionFunction()` method and choose according to your own preference.

Returns a list of values like:

`[-1.0000000000000213, -1.0000000000000053, -0.9999999999999893]`

Better answers still appreciated.